# Equal sized Dock Widgets in PyQt4

Tags: python, widget, size, pyqt, dock

How can I ensure that all dock widgets have the same size irrespective of their content?

Answer (score -1):

You have to set a layout in Qt4.

Check [this](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/x3410) out.